# In the MVC pattern, should the listeners be in the Controler?

Tags: javascript, jquery, model-view-controller

I have buttons that i bind to an event click in jquery :

```
$('myselection').click(myfunction);
```

Should they be in the controller ?

I was thinking so but i encountered a situation that made me doubt. In my js view, i create a form and its submit button. I need to attach an event listener to it such as :

```
$('mybutton').click(myfunctiontosubmit);
```

I can't figure a way to let the controller manage this listener because the button does not exists when i first call my view.

Comment: Where are you implementing the MVC pattern? In your server side code or in your client side code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually not. Their place is in the views, however they could call methods in controllers.

Ember.js has the following description for it's Views.

> Ember.View is the class in Ember responsible for encapsulating templates of HTML content, combining templates with data to render as sections of a page's DOM, and registering and responding to user-initiated events.

As well as having a simplified API to use said events in the view.